# What model should I use for this?

Tags: self-study, model-selection

Consider a dataset with 30 samples. We have a response $Y$ and 12 potential predictors $X_1, \cdots, X_{12}$. We fit two models. The first model $M_1$ includes only $X_1$ and $X_2$ and has an RSS of 8.2. The second model $M_2$ includes only $X_3, \cdots , X_{12}$ and has an RSS of 5.3. Based on AIC, which model do you prefer?

Comment: Is it a homework? If yes `self-study` tag would be appropriate. Another thing is that you provide very little details on your question. Based on AIC *only* you prefer the model with a lower AIC, however in real life you do not use AIC only.

Comment: That's why I'm very confused. That's pretty much the whole question, there are no details.

Answer (score 2):

@Carla it seems you still do not consider the answers you got to be satisfying. It seems that you are *only* asked to choose some model based just on AIC. So, you choose the model with the smallest AIC. Then you have to apply the formula for AIC:

$$AIC = n\ln(RSS/n) + 2k$$

where $n$ is sample size and $k$ the number of parameters and you are done. As you see, the formula for AIC includes both the RSS and the number of terms, so it should answer your doubts.

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb, if you see a difference of least 10 units in the AIC values, then the model with the lower AIC can be considered as the preferred model. But as Tim said, in real applications, you shouldn't just look at one criterion.

Comment: I guess I'm a little skeptical of rules of thumb, but I am very skeptical of this rule that is based on an absolute number. Consider how the difference in AIC values could vary as N, df1 & df2 vary. FWIW, in the past the rule of thumb I have heard is if the 2nd smallest AIC differs from the smallest by >1% of the smallest AIC.

Comment: So what we're saying is that small values of AIC are preferred, so better candidate sets will have smaller RSS and a smaller number of terms? Based on this, model M2 would have the smaller RSS and includes terms X3 to X12, which is 9 terms. Model M1 has only two terms, but a higher RSS. But which is more important; lower RSS or the least number of terms?